# Spring and hibernate integration

Tags: spring, hibernate

I am doing spring and hibernate integration example getting the below exception. Please advise me how to solve it.

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'd' is defined
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:509)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1041)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:273)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:189)
    at com.javatpoint.InsertTest.main(InsertTest.java:14)
```

Comment: You can't expect us to figure it out without sharing *some* code.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to share some code snippets before someone can actually help you here!
Looking at the exception it seems you have created a Class property "d" and marked it as @Autowired.

Spring is trying to find a class of type d or name d registered in its context.
You register a class by using @Service or @Component etc annotation.

Update:(after the OP's comment).
Please ensure you are creating d bean using below code in application context.

```
<bean id="d" class="com.javatpoint.EmployeeDao">  
     <property name="template" ref="template"></property>  
</bean>
```